# jquery does not support mask,any altenative?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement the following without adding new library, any other alternative? because I get java script does not support mask!

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("input").mask("9?99.9?99.9?99.9?99", { placeholder: " " });
});
```

Comment: The alternative is to write all the code that the library uses yourself. Your requirement of not using a library is rather odd, though.

Comment: So, why would you rather re-invent the wheel than just loading one?

Comment: Similar post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513950/javascript-input-text-masking-without-plugin