# How to apply masking in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, masking

I have a  grid in which there is a textbox that is currently accepting numeric numbers. However I want to apply masking in that textbox using javascript or jquery  without any plugin.
I have searched and everywhere they are asking for plug-in.

I tried this solution but it does not work my default value should be 00000-00-000

```
 $("input[name='masknumber']").on("keyup change", function(){
  
  this.value = createMask($("input[name='masknumber']").val());
})

function createMask(string){
return string.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{2})/,"$1-$2-$3");
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want formatted value with 00000-00-000, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Input Text Masking without Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513950/javascript-input-text-masking-without-plugin)

Comment: @Adhitya no it does not answer my question. My textbox value should show by default this format 00000-00-000 and user can only enter in this format.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input which will store original value without masking.

Html:

```html
<input type="text" value="0000000000" id="masknumber">
<input type="text" id="numberWithoutMask" style="display:none;" value="0000000000">
```

JS:

```js
// call function on change
$("#maskNumber").on("keyup change", function () {
    updateValue();
})
// function to update the value with masking
function updateValue() {
    $("#numberWithoutMask").val(destroyMask($("#maskNumber").val()));
    $("#maskNumber").val(createMask($("#numberWithoutMask").val()))
}

function createMask(string) {
    return string.replace(/(\d{5})(\d{2})(\d{3})/, "$1-$2-$3");
}

function destroyMask(string) {
    return string.replace(/\D/g, '').substring(0, 10);
}
updateValue(); // call function to update the default value
```

If you're loading default value, load value to both the inputs.

Comment: It's same function like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513950/javascript-input-text-masking-without-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513950/javascript-input-text-masking-without-plugin)

Comment: What's your requirements??

Comment: Because this is a duplicate post.

Comment: I checked that post when you commented. 
Btw my code is very different from that. And for masking input values, this is the only way without using any plugin.