# Reactjs: Input mask after state.length === 5

Tags: html, reactjs

I wanted to add the `-` char after typing 5 characters like this:

[image]

but I got this:

[image]

My code :

```
interface IAddress {
  bairro: string;
  cep: string;
  cidade: string;
  complemento: string;
  rua: string;
  numero: string;
}
export default function App() {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState<IAddress>({
    bairro: "",
    cep: "",
    cidade: "",
    complemento: "",
    rua: "",
    numero: ""
  });
  const handlerCep = (e: any) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const cep = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    setAddress({
      ...address,
      cep: address.cep.length === 5 ? `${cep}-` : cep
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="tel"
        maxLength={9}
        value={address.cep}
        onChange={(e) => handlerCep(e)}
        //  onBlur={(ev) => findCep(ev)}
        required
        id="cep"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm freaking out at some point and I can't imagine how I can solve this
live example here :

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sea-o4gd5?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Probably you can use something like that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask to resolve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Input Text Masking without Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513950/javascript-input-text-masking-without-plugin)

Comment: I'm having difficulties, could you help me? I delete the key, but whenever I type the 6 I type it replaces the string

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code, first your regexp clears the "-" symbol on line:

```
// update regexp to allow '-'
const cep = value.replace(/[^0-9\-]/g, "")
```

second - you are checking length of property in state, instead of `cep` const variable. State is not yet updated, so you should be interested in checking the length of value from onchange event and update the state with calculated value

```
setAddress({
      ...address,
      // use cep in length check instead of address.cep
      cep: cep.length === 5 ? `${cep}-` : cep
    });
```

After fixing issues above - your should see input is updated as expected. Third issue to think about - case with deletion of characters, I suppose it wont work smoothly with current code.

Comment: hi, can u helpme with regex to no replace "-" ?

Comment: like I found a problem with that, I can use 9 "-"

could i split into groups?

something with group with 5 numbers 1 - and 3 numbers?